# Copy a whole directory with phing

Tags: svn, phing

Does anyone know if its possible to use phing to copy an entire folder with files and sub folders (joomla core download) to another folder, but without the .svn folders.

I have downloaded joomla using SVN, and I want to export it to my joomla dev folder using phing, without the need to have to list every single file type. My plan is to use this to keep my dev updated from the trunk.

I know how to exclude

But cannot find anyway to include everything without listing every file, or trying to guess every file type, just in case I miss something!

Suggestions
Paul

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like phing is modeled after ant?  Try this:

```
<copy todir="my/joomla/dev">
  <fileset dir="joomla/checkout">
    <include>**</include>
    <exclude>**/.svn/**</exclude>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Yes its a php/pear library to do the same as ant, but has some more features. Works quite well. I will check out your idea later :)

Comment: <include name="**"></include>

Answer (score 4):

Try svn export, this will send all the files in your working copy to another directory (sans .svn etc). Then you can phing away.