# Phing copy contents of folder

Tags: php, phing, build-script

I'm trying to move the **contents** of a folder to another destination in Phing. I can't directly download the contents from SVN, because they're in a zip. After the file is unzipped, I want to move the contents.

I found this syntax, but it doesn't work:
[Copy a whole directory with phing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015412/copy-a-whole-directory-with-phing)

Thanks!

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etiher the post you've linked is wrong or there where changes in Phing since that answer.

Here comes a working `build.xml` that copies `test` to `test2` (expect of `.svn` folders). The syntax is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Hexdump" default="build">
  <target name="build">
    <copy todir="test2">
        <fileset dir="test">
            <include name="**"></include>
            <exclude name="**/.svn/**"></exclude>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

You can refer to the [Phing Core Tasks Documentation](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apbs09.html)

Comment: The link is broken. Anyway, thanks for the code! It's working for me as well :)

Comment: @tftd Seems like they have updated and enhanced their documentation. :) I have updated the link.