# How to copy only a specific list of files from one directory to another using phing?

Tags: php, git, phing, file-copying, fileset

I have this list of file changes between two git revisions in a variable `rolloutChanges` -

```
<exec command="git diff -–name-only ${box.git_version} ${target.git_version}" outputProperty="rolloutChanges" dir="${dir.scratchpad}" />
```

I am not sure how this variable should ideally be iterated, may be by preparing it in some other standard format recognizable by phing.

I saw this answer which involves foreach with target - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459526/351903, but did not get a hold of what is happening there. I could not even run the solution in my setup.

I checked the [documentation for fileset](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/FileSet.html) but don't see any way in which variables are supported. Also checked this [Copy a whole directory with phing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015412/copy-a-whole-directory-with-phing)

**Updates**

I understood the usage of foreach and target, and put it in my code, after the exec command -

```
<exec command="git diff --name-only ${box.git_version} ${target.git_version}" outputProperty="rolloutChanges" dir="${dir.scratchpad}/${dir.subdir}" />
<foreach list="${rolloutChanges}" param="eachFileToRollout" target="buildlang" />
```

And I have the following task -

```
<target name="buildlang">
        <echo>Overwriting ${eachFileToRollout} </echo>
    </target>
```

Now, the rolloutChanges variable contains a string, something like this (taken from console) -

```
app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/file1.php
app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/file2.php
```

So, the output of the target block is this (Notice that there is only one element in the list, Overwriting gets printed only once) -

```
Overwriting app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/file1.php 
app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/file2.php
```

**Is there a native phing way of putting the output of the exec into a list, such that as many elements are created as there are files in the output?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your foreach solution work, you need to specify the delimiter, which is a newline in your case.

[ForeachTask](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/ForeachTask.html) provides a `delimiter` attribute (default value: `,`). Set it to `&#10;` in order to separate the string at Unix-style newlines. The platform-independent value would be `${line.separator}`.

Comment: Oh I missed the delimeter attribute :(. Thanks a lot.